# Lendo arquivo csv com Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Sou iniciante em Kotlin e tenho a seguinte classe para fazer a leitura de um arquivo csv:

```
@Service
class ClienteImportService {
    fun obtemTodosMsisdn(args: Array<File>) {
        val reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(toString()))
        val csvToBean = CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
                .withType(Cliente::class)
                .build()
        val clientes = csvToBean.parse()

        for (cliente in clientes)
            System.out.println(cliente)

    }
}
```

Estou tomando erro na linha que contém 
            val csvToBean = CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)

Que é o seguinte:

Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in constructor CsvToBeanBuilder(reader: Reader!)
Please specify it explicitly.

O que faço?

Comment: Já tentou passar a classe do Java ao invés da do Kotlin? (`withType(Cliente::class.java)`)

Comment: Já sim! Mas o erro permanece :(

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly, como agradecimento e respeito à ajuda, consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

val csvToBean = CsvToBeanBuilder<Cliente>(reader)
                .withType(Cliente::class.java)
                .build()

Comment: Oi @MSSantana, fique a vontade para postar sua resposta. É interessante que o Kotlin não conseguiu inferir o parâmetros genérico, que bom que passar ele explicitamente resolveu :).